# "pnpm dev" pops unhandledRejection errno -4094

Tags: reactjs, debugging, next.js, pnpm

i've been making cna project.
However, when I try to enter the page via developer mode using the 'pnpm dev' command, I get the error below.

1. You cannot enter the page with that error.
2. If I try consistently, rather than getting that error over and over again, I can get in about 2 out of 10 times without error.
3. but even in that situation, if you modify the code slightly and save it, the page will crash with that error.

```
[Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'C:\Users\jhs00\Documents\workplace\sign-mall\.next\static\chunks\amp.js'] {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\jhs00\\Documents\\workplace\\sign-mall\\.next\\static\\chunks\\amp.js'
}
- error unhandledRejection: [Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'C:\Users\jhs00\Documents\workplace\projectname\.next\static\chunks\amp.js'] {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\jhs00\\Documents\\workplace\\projectname\\.next\\static\\chunks\\amp.js'
}
```

I am currently using a Windows operating system and use vscode. If anyone has experienced the same error as me, and if anyone has solved it, please help...

Comment: Try to delete the folder `.next` and rerun

Comment: i did that process but it happens again after few save

Comment: There is an opened [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/51082) at nextjs repo that looks pretty like yours, not resolved sadly. Try ro play with different nextjs versions..

Comment: That's too bad, thanks for the info.